# Hibernate and JPA project : invalid column name error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to publish my data in json format on port 8080.But
I tried hard but couldn't find the error.
I hope we find a solution

I'm getting this error:

```
2020-09-07 01:36:12.996  INFO 9108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-07 01:36:13.014  INFO 9108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 18 ms
2020-09-07 01:36:13.550  WARN 9108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
2020-09-07 01:36:13.550 ERROR 9108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Geçersiz sütun adı 'ogr_id'.
2020-09-07 01:36:13.591 ERROR 9108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Geçersiz sütun adı 'ogr_id'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:602) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3206) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2341) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2094) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2056) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1415) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.DataAccess.HibernateOgrenciDal.getAll(HibernateOgrenciDal.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.DataAccess.HibernateOgrenciDal$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fe8bd5d9.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.DataAccess.HibernateOgrenciDal$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ce14d711.getAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Business.OgrenciManeger.getAll(OgrenciManeger.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Business.OgrenciManeger$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2b9d4bcd.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Business.OgrenciManeger$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d98916d.getAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.RestApi.OgrenciController.getAll(OgrenciController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

My sql server code:

```
Create Table ogrenci(
ogrId int identity(1,1) Primary Key NOT NULL,
ogrAd varchar(50) NOT NULL,
ogrSoyad varchar(50) not null
)

Insert into ogrenci Values
('Serhat','Soral'),
('Mehmet','Arıkan'),
('Hüseyin','Akbulat')
```

My entity class:

```
package com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="ogrenci")
public class Ogrenci {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ogrId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ogrId;
    @Column(name="ogrAd")
    private String ogrAd;
    @Column(name="ogrSoyad")
    private String ogrSoyad;
    
    public Ogrenci() {
        
    }
    public Ogrenci(int ogrId, String ogrAd, String ogrSoyad) {
        super();
        this.ogrId = ogrId;
        this.ogrAd = ogrAd;
        this.ogrSoyad = ogrSoyad;
    }

    public int getOgrId() {
        return ogrId;
    }

    public void setOgrId(int ogrId) {
        this.ogrId = ogrId;
    }

    public String getOgrAd() {
        return ogrAd;
    }

    public void setOgrAd(String ogrAd) {
        this.ogrAd = ogrAd;
    }

    public String getOgrSoyad() {
        return ogrSoyad;
    }

    public void setOgrSoyad(String ogrSoyad) {
        this.ogrSoyad = ogrSoyad;
    }
    
}
```

Data Access Package:

```
package com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.DataAccess;
import com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Entities.Ogrenci;
import java.util.List;

public interface IOgrenciDal {

    public List<Ogrenci> getAll();

}
```

```
package com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.DataAccess;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Entities.Ogrenci;
@Repository
public class HibernateOgrenciDal implements IOgrenciDal {

    private EntityManager entityManeger;
    
    
    @Autowired
    public HibernateOgrenciDal(EntityManager entityManeger) {
    
        this.entityManeger = entityManeger;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Ogrenci> getAll() {
        Session session=entityManeger.unwrap(Session.class);
    List<Ogrenci> ogrenciler=session.createQuery("from Ogrenci",Ogrenci.class).getResultList();
        return ogrenciler;
    }

}
```

Business Package:

```
package com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Business;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Entities.Ogrenci;

public interface IOgrenciService {
    List<Ogrenci> getAll();

}
```

```
package com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Business;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.DataAccess.IOgrenciDal;
import com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Entities.Ogrenci;

@Service
public class OgrenciManeger implements IOgrenciService {

    private IOgrenciDal ogrenciDal;
    
    @Autowired
    public OgrenciManeger(IOgrenciDal ogrenciDal) {
        
        this.ogrenciDal = ogrenciDal;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Ogrenci> getAll() {
        
        return this.ogrenciDal.getAll();
    }
}
```

And Controller Class:

```
package com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.RestApi;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Business.IOgrenciService;
import com.example.hibernateAndJpa2.Entities.Ogrenci;

@RestController
public class OgrenciController {

    private IOgrenciService ogrenciService;

    @Autowired
    public OgrenciController(IOgrenciService ogrenciService) {
        this.ogrenciService = ogrenciService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Ogrenci> getAll(){
        
        return ogrenciService.getAll();
    }   
}
```

Finally, application.properties and pom.xml:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=JavaCalisma1
spring.datasource.username=serhat
spring.datasource.password=serhat
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernateAndJpa2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hibernateAndJpa2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
           
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
          <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
         <version>8.4.1.jre11</version>
       </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm waiting for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your persistence configuration is mapping camelcase to underscore.
To fix that you can replace the field name strategy with:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy
```

You have an explanation here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot

Or you could just rename to column to ogrid. It will imply to amend the script to create the table and the name in the column annotation.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.  I added ` spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl ` to the application.properties file.